# Is Ubuntu Openstack free or does it cost money?

Tags: openstack, cloud

I have read through the links on ubuntu.com for cloud and also read through few questions asked previously on askubuntu, but am still confused, hence this question (appreciate if you don't mark this as duplicate, but help me understand):

1. Suppose I wish to install Openstack (on more than 10 nodes) on Ubuntu server following the manual method (referring to Openstack installation guide) - I guess this is called Ubuntu Openstack (as its packaged for Ubuntu).

   1. Do I have to pay any license fees for this Openstack installation?
   2. Can I still purchase support for openstack, to get bug fixes with a  faster response (for production deployment)
   3. Instead of manual installation, could I use Juju, MaaS for installing Openstack on Ubuntu server for free for more than 10 nodes? or it is only available for Canonical distribution of Ubuntu Openstack?
2. Suppose I want to use the Canonical distribution of Ubuntu Openstack

   1. I understand that I can use it for free (no license fees) for upto 10 nodes - Is this correct even if I want to use for commercial/production purpose, or this is only for some beta release etc.?
   2. Can I still buy only support (for my production use case)for this installation of upto 10 nodes (where I am not required to pay for any license fees for upto 10 nodes)?

Would really appreciate any help from Canonical in helping me understand these scenarios.

Comment: Can anyone help on this please?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for getting in touch. My name is James Wengraf and you can reach me on james.wengraf@canonical.com or 0044 207 630 2463 and I sit on the Cloud Platforms team at our HQ.

In answer to your questions:

1. No
2. Yes
3. Automated installation better route to go, for many reasons. Please refer to Ubuntu OpenStack Autopilot, which will automate the installation for you. Our Landscape Systems management tool can provision up to 10 nodes for you  to test on.

---

2. In detail:

   1. Yes, correct. You can use for free.
   2. Yes, you can buy only support. There are caveats though. The cloud must be built using our tools.

I would recommend that you contact me so we can discuss further. I would like to know more about your use case. I can hopefully also give you some insight into what other OpenStack end users are doing.

Finally, for production workloads, I would actually recommend our BootStack offering. It will save you time and money and is one of our most advanced cloud platform products, specifically catering to smaller scale cloud deployments.

Comment: So can one use it for free on more than 10 nodes or not? Can you please give some examples of using cloud for free with large setup?